# Excel Name Manager Link keeps reappearing after deleted

Tags: excel, hyperlink, reference

I have an Excel document that links to an external document in a location I do not have access to. I am able to delete the reference via Name Manager. However, any time I make updates to the Excel document (it's a template and constantly being updated), the link reappears in Name Manager.

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to prevent the link from reappearing every time?

Comment: Have you broken the links in File > Info > Edit Links to Files (bottom-right corner)?

Comment: I am working in Excel 2013, but in Data > Connections Group > Edit Links, 'Edit Links' is grayed out so I can't break the link.

Comment: When you say it's a template, you do mean that it has the extension xltx, correct?

Comment: No that is irrelevant, I'm just trying to state that it is constantly being updated. It is an xlsm (macro-enabled).